# updating java by setting home path variable

Tags: bash, java, environment-variables, jdk, openjdk

I have a system, where i try to set the java version from 1.7 to 1.8.

First i downloaded the jdk, then set the `JAVA_HOME` global variable.

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk.1.8.0_60`

than validate version

`echo $JAVA_HOME`
outputs
`/usr/java/jdk.1.8.0_60`

but the version is still the same.

`java -version`
outputs 
`java version "1.7.0_75"`

Answer (score 0):

Then you have (at least) two java versions on your machine, right?

Besides setting `JAVA_HOME` you probably want to modify the `PATH` variable, and you want to change it persistent. Assuming you use e.g. the `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file for the purpose, you can add these lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk.1.8.0_60
PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH"
```

Then relogin (in case of `~/.profile`) or simply close and reopen the terminal (in case of `~/.bashrc`).